# Mysql update table column from one database to another

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a script that updates from:

tendesig_zink_production | euid0_hikashop_product | product_quantity

to:

tendesig_zink_dev | euid0_hikashop_product | product_quantity

I have to do this because our inventory numbers are stored on the production instance. so before pushing a new version from our dev instance i have to update the dev's inventories from production prior to the push. I am a lot rusty with my mySQL, this is what i have so far I need to know what the proper query would be though.

```
<?php
$host1="localhost"; // destination
$base1="tendesig_zink_dev";
$user1="tendesig_zink";
$password1="1,&#GZAWiB5z";

$host2="localhost"; //source
$base2="tendesig_zink_production";
$user2="tendesig_zink";
$password2="1,&#GZAWiB5z";


$conection1 = @mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $password1) 
or die("Error reaching destination<br>".mysql_error()." nr eroare: ".mysql_errno());
print "Succesfuly connected 1! <br>";

$Db1 = @mysql_select_db($base1, $conection1)
or die("Error reaching destination database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
print "Database1 reached!<br>"; 

$conection2 = @mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $password2) 
or die("Error reaching source<br>".mysql_error()." nr eroare: ".mysql_errno());
print "Succesfuly connected 2!<br>";

$Db2 = @mysql_select_db($base2, $conection2)
or die("Error reaching source database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
print "Database2 reached!!<br>"; 



$query = 'create table destination_table select * from second_database.source_table'; 
//echo "<br>".$query."<br>"; 
$result2 = mysql_query($query2, $conection1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error().'||'.mysql_errno());



mysql_close($conection1);
mysql_close($conection2);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. You want to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE destination_database.destination_table LIKE source_database.source_table
```

Then run this:

```
INSERT INTO destination_database.destination_table 
SELECT * FROM source_database.source_table
```

In (untested) PHP code:

```
$create_query = 'CREATE TABLE destination_database.destination_table LIKE source_database.source_table'; 
$result = mysql_query($create_query, $conection1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error().'||'.mysql_errno());

$insert_query = 'INSERT INTO destination_database.destination_table SELECT * FROM source_database.source_table'; 
$result = mysql_query($insert_query , $conection1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error().'||'.mysql_errno());
```

Comment: I think the query i am looking for needs to be different. what i need is an UPDATE db1 from SELECT db2

Comment: In that case, please be more specific about your problem. It is not clear what rows need to be updated or what conditions you are applying. Are you looking for something like inserting new rows and updating existing rows? If so, please provide your schema; otherwise, it's impossible to tell what you might need.